# Can we connect azure event hub with azure notification hub?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-eventhub

I sent the message from windows form application to azure event hub. After I using data stream analytics for some real time operation and get data from event hub. After that operation I sent result message to event hub. Now I want to display the result message to users through azure notification hub using mobile app(android or windows mobile app). Can we connect azure notification hub and azure event hub directly?.

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot be done directly, some intermediate layer should get a message from the Event Hub and then send to mobile devices through the Notification Hub.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Give some idea how to connect azure event hub and notification hub using intermediate layer. what are the intermediate layers are available?.

Comment: By intermediate layer I mean a peace of code written by you :) It may be hosted in Azure or on your  private server.