# Azure event hub receiver in android

Tags: android, push-notification, raspberry-pi, azure-eventhub

I want to implement a push notification functionality in my android application using Azure event hub. Being a novice, I am not much aware of how to proceed ahead with it.

I am using Raspberry Pi as a sender (Azure event hub sender) which is working as expected. For receiving the messages sent from Raspberry Pi, I want my Android device to handle it (as an Azure event hub receiver).

I came across *Broadcast Receiver* concept, which I think can be used here. Need inputs whether I am on the right track, and will be grateful, if some examples are provided.

Please suggest an optimum way to achieve this.

Code for sending the events to Azure event hub from Raspberry Pi:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService

sbs = ServiceBusService(api_key["namespace"], shared_access_key_name=api_key["policy_name"], shared_access_key_value=api_key["policy_secret"])

sbs.send_event('eventhubname', '{ "DeviceId":"deviceId1", "Temperature":"10.0" }')
```

I referred these links to implement sender and receiver in .net console application which is working as expected. Need to implement the same in Android.

[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/](http://Microsoft%20Azure%20doc%20reference%20-%20Get%20started%20with%20Event%20Hubs)

I am also able to implement sender in using Azue Python SDK (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-servicebus/0.20.1)

Comment: show us code! How do you send events? How do you expect to receive them..

Comment: @Blundell Updated OP. Please check.

Comment: So you send it using some azure SDK, what does the azure SDK say about receiving them on an Android device?

Comment: @Blundell That's what I am not confirmed about yet. Probably lack of documentation. It would be really helpful, if you provide me with some suggestions.

Comment: well how did you do the serverside code? You must have followed some online docs, but you haven't linked anything here

Comment: @Blundell The links which I used as a reference are updated in OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98438/discussion-between-ali-waris-and-blundell).

Comment: We don't need to continue in the chat :-) all your answers are right here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/ do that then come back to stack overflow with a new - direct question. good luck!

Comment: @Blundell I already checked this link before. I am confused whether 'Event' hub and 'Notifications' hub implementation is the same?

Comment: you'll find out when you try? And if not you'll have learnt two things! But I'd say yes it is 'notification' is Android terminology and 'Event' web

Comment: @Blundell This makes sense. Thanks for the quick insight; will surely dive in deeper and will keep the post updated if faced any issues. :)

Comment: I'd advise closing this, and if you have issues creating a new question. This comment section is already too big :-)

Comment: @Blundell can you please provide any documentation for implementing 'azure event hub notifications' in android? I went through event hub but couldn't find anything where the GCM API key gets attached to event hub unlike notification hub. Can you please help..?

Comment: someone else seems to be doing what you're trying here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27367182/413127 not the answer you wanted :)

Comment: @Blundell So is it correct to conclude that for implementing push notifications on Android, "Notification hub" is to be used?